# Linear fourth-order parabolic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, parabolic-pde

I have this parabolic equation
$$u_t=u_{xx}-\epsilon u_{xxxx}$$
Where can I find references on the existence and uniqueness of the solution?